# snakemake non-python dependencies

Tags: conda, snakemake

I use snakemake in my existing conda env where other tools are also installed, e.g., R, julia, etc. I prefer install and upgrade for snakemake via `pip` instead of native conda command given I found it be more stable and less of conflicting nature with ever-spinning conda wheel to resolve conflicts.

I read on [snakemake installation page](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#installation-via-pip) that it has certain non-python dependencies and so pip may not be a good option. I tried finding those in [source code](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake) but better if I get specific info.

Comment: _I prefer install and upgrade for snakemake via pip instead of native conda command give I found it to be more stable and less of conflicting nature with ever-spinning conda wheel to resolve conflicts._ I think resolving dependencies should take 2 minutes at most, in my experience every time it takes any longer than that there’s an issue somewhere. I would not be surprised if liberal/unsafe use of pip in your Conda environments may have actually broken something. Take a look at https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment.

Comment: Wait, are you using the base environment, too? Your best bet is probably to just carefully reinstall Conda.